# Google App Engine cannot find gdata module

Tags: python, google-app-engine, macos, gdata, google-data-api

I can run a simple "Hello World" Google App Engine application on localhost with no problems.  However, when I add the line "import gdata.auth" to my Python script I get "ImportError: No module named gdata.auth".

I have installed the gdata module and added the following line to my .bashrc:

```
export PYTHONPATH=$PYTHONPATH:/Library/Python/2.5/site-packages/
```

Is there anything else I need to do?  Thanks.

EDIT: The strange thing is that if I run python from a shell and type "import gdata.auth" I do not get an error.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your .bashrc is not known to Google App Engine. Make sure the `gdata` directory (with all its proper contents) is under your application's main directory!

See [this article](http://code.google.com/appengine/articles/gdata.html), particularly (and I quote):

> To use this library with your Google
>   App Engine application, simply place
>   the library source files in your
>   application's directory, and import
>   them as you usually would. The source
>   directories you need to upload with
>   your application code are src/gdata
>   and src/atom. Then, be sure to call
>   the
>   `gdata.alt.appengine.run_on_appengine`
>   function on each instance of a
>   gdata.service.GDataService object.
>   There's nothing more to it than that!

Comment: This is how I got it to work the other week for me, just upload the code into a gdata directory and you should be sorted.

Answer (score 1):

The gdata client library installation script installs the modules in the wrong directory for ubuntu python installation.

```
sudo mv /usr/local/lib/python2.6/dist-packages/* /usr/lib/python2.6/dist-packages
```

Answer (score 0):

try adding this to your script:

```
import sys
sys.path.append('<directory where gdata.auth module is saved>')
import gdata.auth
```

Comment: no I don't think it caused pain - I voted it down because I don't think it answered the question.