# Google App Engine Can't Find PyObjC / Recognize PYTHONPATH

Tags: python, macos, google-app-engine, pyobjc

I upgraded to google app engine sdk 1.7.6 and was greeted with

> UserWarning: Detecting source code changes is not supported because your Python version does not include PyObjC (http://pyobjc.sourceforge.net/). Please install PyObjC

I installed PyObjC by doing

```
sudo easy_install -U pyobjc-core
sudo easy_install -U pyobjc
```

I then added the following to my .bash_profile

```
export PYTHONPATH=/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python:$PYTHONPATH
```

as the `PyObjC.pth` file is located there.

Running python from a terminal and then typing `import objc` worked, so I'm assuming PyObjC was installed correctly.

Google App Engine still gave me the error, so I tried adding the same path to ~/.MacOSX/environment.plist

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple Computer//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
  <dict>
    <key>DISPLAY</key>
    <string>:0.0</string>
<key>PYTHONPATH</key>
    <string>/usr/local/Cellar/pil/1.1.7/lib/python2.7/site-packages:/System/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/Extras/lib/python</string>
  </dict>
</plist>
```

That didn't work either.

Overall I'm very confused about where Google App Engine looks for libraries, and whether or not it cares about the PYTHONPATH, or if there are multiple PYTHONPATHs. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1035554/google-app-engine-cannot-find-gdata-module) question seems to imply that it doesn't care about .bash_profile defined PYTHONPATHs. I had a lot of trouble getting the PIL image library installed, too.

My main python install directory that Google App Engine uses is

```
/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.7/bin/
```

which is not where the pyobjc library is installed.

related questions:
[Do I seriously need to install Xcode and compile PyObjC as a result of 1.7.6 update?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15513642/do-i-seriously-need-to-install-xcode-and-compile-pyobjc-as-a-result-of-1-7-6-upd)

Answer (score 0):

I ended up installing PyObjC from source rather than using easy_install, restarted Google App Engine, and it appears to have worked.

And on another machine, the easy_install method worked out of the box, so it was probably just an issue with installing to the right python directory (as Ronald commented).

Still would love to hear any insights about whether GAE cares about PYTHONPATH. I believe I had to edit `~/.MacOSX/environment.plist` to get the PIL image library to work.

Comment: The installation with easy_install probably installed pyobjc in the wrong python installation (the sys.prefix for /usr/bin/python, instead of the one for /Library/Frameworks/Python).

Comment: Got a question for you, how do you install PyObjc into the right directory? Mine isn't working either and I noticed that it's installing in "/Library/Python/2.7" instead of "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/versions/2.7" which is what Google Appengine uses.

Comment: how are you installing? Different installers will install to different directories... when I installed from source it put it the place my GAE sdk uses, but not when I installed using easy_install