# I keep getting the error message no module named gdata

Tags: python, django, google-api, youtube-api, pip

I keep getting the error message no module named gdata. after I did this

```
 pip install --upgrade google-api-python-client
```

so I tried this

```
pip install gdata
```

and it installed

```
gdata 2.0.18
```

But I still keep getting the error message. If I do pip list I get

```
    beautifulsoup4 (4.4.1)
    dj-database-url (0.4.0)
    Django (1.9.2)
    django-bootstrap-pagination (1.6.1)
    django-crispy-forms (1.6.0)
    django-haystack (2.4.1)
    django-markdown-deux (1.0.5)
    django-pagedown (0.1.1)
    django-taggit (0.18.1)
    feedparser (5.2.1)
    future (0.15.2)
    gdata (2.0.18)
    google-api-python-client (1.5.1)
    gunicorn (19.4.5)
    html5lib (0.9999999)
    httplib2 (0.9.2)
    lxml (3.6.0)
    markdown2 (2.3.1)
    oauth2client (2.2.0)
    oauthlib (1.1.2)
    Pillow (3.2.0)
    pip (8.1.2)
    psycopg2 (2.6.1)
    pyasn1 (0.1.9)
    pyasn1-modules (0.0.8)
    requests (2.9.1)
    requests-oauthlib (0.6.1)
    rsa (3.4.2)
    setuptools (20.6.7)
    simplejson (3.8.2)
    six (1.10.0)
    tweepy (3.5.0)
    uritemplate (0.6)
    wheel (0.29.0)
    whitenoise (3.0)
    Whoosh (2.7.4)
```

I'm using this in a django app if that matters. What's my issue?

EDIT If if I use python shell and try to import it. I get this error message

```
      Traceback (most recent call last):
      File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
      File "/Users/ray/Desktop/myheroku/practice/lib/python3.5/site-packages/gdata/__init__.py", line 27, in <module>
        import atom
      File "/Users/ray/Desktop/myheroku/practice/lib/python3.5/site-packages/atom/__init__.py", line 133, in <module>
        CreateClassFromXMLString)
      File "/Users/ray/Desktop/myheroku/practice/lib/python3.5/site-packages/atom/__init__.py", line 97, in mark_deprecated
        optional_warn_function.func_name = f.func_name
    AttributeError: 'function' object has no attribute 'func_name'
```

EDIT I just read this on [git](https://github.com/Nejuf/gdata-python-client/issues/370)

```
The client library is only designed for Python 2.4 - 2.6. See Issue 229: 
http://code.google.com/p/gdata-python-client/issues/detail?    

id=229&q=label:Type-Defect

It also support 2.6+ but not 3.* as yet. For 3.0 support please track
```

http://code.google.com/p/gdata-python-client/issues/detail?id=229

So this may be my issue. This is from may 25, 2015

The documentation says up to 3.4 I'm using 3.5 so I guess it won't work

Comment: Is this relevant at all? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1035554/google-app-engine-cannot-find-gdata-module

Comment: @RandomDavis You have an awsome name for an esper on a netflix series, but no it doesn't. Thanks though. I actually saw that just before I made this post

Comment: do show your exact import statement